# Grails GORM locks table when updating a DB table

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, transactional

I am iterating over a large dataset and updating each row.
The data locked as long as its loops and the changes are not saved until its all done

My Code:

In the controller

```
stocks.each { stock ->

        def s = stockService.updateData(stock)
        stockService.save s
    }
```

and the save method in the service is the only on with @Transactional:

```
@Transactional
private void save(Stock stock) {
    stock.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want that the datasets are locked the whole time, you can create a transaction for each save:

```
private void save(Stock stock) {
    Stock.withNewTransaction {
        stock.attach()
        stock.save()
    }
}
```

The disadvantage is, that a rollback of all changed datasets is not possible on errors.

Comment: When running it in a loop. I get:

     Caused by:     org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection : [xxx.Stock.estimations#718]; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions.

Comment: Ok, it seems that Stock has a “to-many” relation to "estimations" and that estimations are bound with the other session.
You could attach all estimations to the new transaction. Or you could call "merge()" instead of "save()". Maybe it could help.